# AWS instance when self-hosted via cloudlfare is stuck on the login page,when logged in,it just deauthenticates and returns to the login

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-hosting, cloudflare

I am hosting an AWS instance and running filecloud on it.It works perfectly when accessed with the public IPv4 DNS.I added a CNAME record on cloudflare to connect it to my personal domain. When accessed through this, the page opens up normally but I can't log into accounts(neither the admin nor the users). It logs in for a second before the page is redirected to the same login page again.
I tried to toggle the proxy,changing the subdomain and even using the 'A' record type,but the same problem still persists.
Any suggestions?